# In Power App How to filter created by Me and Status

Tags: sharepoint-online, filter, powerapp

I had written below formula to get item created by me but how to add one more filter of status = Draft

```
Filter(test,Lower('Created By'.Email)=Lower(CurrentUser))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Filter(test,Lower('Created By'.Email)=Lower(CurrentUser) && Status="Draft")
```

**official documentation**: [Filter, Search, and LookUp functions in PowerApps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup).

**Similar question**: [Filter multiple condition](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps-Formerly/Filter-multiple-condition/td-p/142832).